# How to Decry-pt encrypted BTC private key

Tags: wallet-recovery

I have public key and Encrypted Private key. I need to decrypt the private key or find the password. I need your help to do this.

Thanks all

Comment: the goal of the bitcoin system is to have independency from third parties, or better "be your own bank". With all threats and opportunities. So some thought came into the system, as to the way, private keys are handled. They cannot be calculated from public keys (as per today's knowledge), and when the private key is encrypted, again the goal is to make it only de-cryptable by knowing the secret. Every wallet has it's set of rules to encrypt the private key, and if there is no known back door, it is highly impossible that you find your private key again...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot obtain the private key from the public key.

Without the password (encryption key) you cannot decrypt a competently encrypted private-key.

You cannot obtain the password (encryption key) from a competently encrypted private key. The best you can do is hope the password was poorly chosen and try to guess it thousands of times or more.